# Phase shift of a light wave due to reflection at the interface of a higher refractive index medium

Tags: reflection, interference

If a light wave is traveling from a medium of a refractive index $n_1$ to another medium of a refractive index $n_2$, why does it undergo a phase shift of a $180^○$ when the reflection takes place at an interface when $n_2 > n_1$?

Comment: I have no short answer for you, suitable for a StackExchange post. Instead, I recommend “Internal Reflection and ATR Spectroscopy” by Milosevic. I learned a lot from that book, though I need to refer to it to be able to reproduce answers to questions like this ;) https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118309742

Comment: @W_vH thank you!